# ASCII text files

Tags: operating-systems, ascii

Given a file contains ASCII characters is there anyway to determine the operating system of origin?

This needs to work regardless of the existence of newline characters

Comment: I am willing to be proven wrong and I'm not confident enough to make this an actual answer, but I would say no. That is kind of the point of cross platform standards.

Comment: No;  Its not possible.  An program can write a text file like you describe in any number of ways.  I could write a program that ran on ANY operating system and the output file would be identical.

Comment: The only thing about the origin if a file I can think of, is 'creation time'. that might be an avenue to look down if at the binary/hex level it's distinctive to an OS, and even after a copy, but I doubt it. don't get your hopes up

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this even matter to you?  What problem are you trying to solve by being able to detect this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Way.

The most would be Windows uses \r\n and unix \n,  And even then,  you can write a file with *nix line endings in Windows and vice versa. but if no new line characters.. no way.

You can't see the origin of the file, there's no tag of any kind